# Query string in <iframe>

Tags: php, html, iframe

I am trying to call a query string in `<iframe>`. I tried different ways. When I run the script ill get:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)......\print.php on line 184

Something in `src="./print.php?id='. $_GET['id'] .'"` goes wrong. I tried to access `print.php?id=25` and there where also no errors on that page.

Does anybody know whats wrong with my code?

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['id'])) 
{ 
    ?>
<iframe width="100%" height="900px" src="./print.php?id='. $_GET['id'] .'"></iframe>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html code you use `$_GET[]`?!

try this

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['id'])){ 
?>
    <iframe width="100%" height="900px" src="./print.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"></iframe>
<?php
}
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['id'])) { 
   echo '<iframe width="100%" height="900px" src="./print.php?id='.$_GET['id'].'"></iframe>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thats the solution :D Thanks

Comment: ;) If this is solution for your question accept this answer